# Monitor API hits queries on a RTC server and kill them after a timeout

Tags: api, rational-team-concert, ibm-jazz

I'm using RTC plain java library to make an API call to the Jazz server to fetch components, projects, etc. Is there any way to monitor the database queries triggered on the server-side either through UI or by using any tool and kill them after a timeout.

Although we can see the active queries under 'Activr Service' page on UI, there isn't a way to kill them.